# Proving that one can always find a rational number between two real numbers

Tags: proof-verification

I recently attempted to prove the following statement:

"If $x$ and $y$ are real numbers, with $x \ < \ y$ , there is a rational number $r$ such that $x \ < \ r \ < \ y$"

This problem came from a book on proofs that I am currently reading. The author equips the reader with the **additional** information that...

---

*consider that the following proof is* **true**:

"For all real numbers $\epsilon > 0$ and $a > 0$, there is an integer $n>0$ such that $\frac {a}{n} < \epsilon$"

---

So, long story short, I came up with the proof and the crucial bit that I developed, which allows me to conclude that the initial statement is true is that:

"$n*\epsilon > 1$"

I will show you the solution manual's proof...I had all of the exact steps besides the aforementioned one:

[image: Author's Proof]

As you can see, the author decides to state the following:

"$n*\epsilon > 2$"

Now, the purpose of this line (in general) is to establish that you can multiply $x$ and $y$ by some integer that is sufficiently large to ensure that **at least one integer** will exist between $n*x$ and $n*y$.

However, the I am confused as to why the author decided to use the number $2$ and not $1$. Was the decision arbitrary? Am I missing something?

As far as I can tell, as long as the subtractive difference between two numbers is greater than $1$, you are guaranteed to find an integer that exists *between* the two numbers.

Would my version of the proof have been equally valid?

Comment: Maybe related:https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Between_two_Real_Numbers_exists_Rational_Number

Comment: I can't see why (s)he used $2$. I would agree that $1$ works just as well for the reason you stated (difference $> 1$).